# Position DIV below absolute DIVS (footer)

Tags: css, html, position, footer, absolute

I'd be glad if you could help me with some positioning. Here is the [website](http://fami.nazwa.pl/cc/apro).
Problem is my footer. I can't make it show always below container (if text container goes below img). If text is short enough to not go below img its ok. I tried many solutions, but non of them seemed to work for me. Solution to this could be making slider div with background, but I can't use it because I want it to fit the screen (so I need to use `<img>` inside it.) Any help would be much appreciated. Long story short:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="slider"><img with background</div>
<div id="page absolute div">
content
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Another solution could be stretching "container" height when "page" div keeps getting bigger, but its not possible (from what I know) because its position is absolute.
[EDITED]
www[dot]fami[dot]nazwa.pl/cc/apro/wp-content/themes/apro/style.css
div id dol is footer
how website looks to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjY2a.png
i want footer (div id dol) to be below that absolute div with content

Comment: We need to see the CSS if we are to help.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your page, so I don’t understand what you are trying to do. However, have you considered using floats and clearing with your footer?

Comment: Oh I see your problem now. However, tried to manipulate the html and couldnt get it working like you want. 

Maybe you could put the image as the background of an absolute empty div with fixed height and change the background image if you can get the same effect as you have now.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Answer (score -3):

using firefox to see the code and css, I can't find a 'footer'....?

Comment: This is not an answer. Should have been a comment.

Comment: good lord, someone actual took the time to think/say/and act to say "hey, that doesn't mean anything in this post?". At the time, I took the time to visit the site with an appropriate tool and check the code/css and couldn't read any of the language and didn't see the KEY div the OP was asking about. Very relevant at the time. If you were not the actual 'down voter' I apologize but down voting was enough. Adding your comment wasn't related to the posting AT ALL. At least my comment was in the direction of providing help. Man, it's like Geocitites all over again.

Comment: I downvoted; I also believe in giving explainations on downvotes, in order to improve the answer. A downvote can be erased if, for example, the answer is modified. What you say is correct: you took the time and didn't see what the OP was talking about. **So why putting it as an answer**? This is exactly what comments should be for. [** *Answers* should always provide an answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette). Don't take it too personally: SO is about a community of answers, and about improving them whenever possible.